# Read dynamic table values with button click

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

I need little help with jquery.
I have a dynamical grid that takes the value from the database.
Sometimes the grid can have 5,6 ... 20... 30... rows and I have to show their value on the button click. 
Value from the labels need to be shown in one column and values from the textbox or ddl need to be shown in other column.

The problem is that number of label's can be 3, 4 ..20... and sometimes in second column value can be textbox and sometimes ddl, that depends on the database.

```
<table id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
            <tbody><tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
                <th scope="col">Karakteristike</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">Opis</th>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
                <td>
                            <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_0" mycustomattr="foo" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">GRP Total_Thickness</span>


                        </td><td>
                            <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_0" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">1</span>


                        </td><td>

                             <select name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl02$ddlOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_ddlOpis_0" margin-left="100px" class="ddl" style="font-family: Georgia; height: 35px; width: 142px; display: none;">

                </select>
                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl02$txtBoxOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_0" margin-left="100px" class="txtbox" style="font-family:Georgia;height:28px;width:130px;" type="text">


                        </td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
                <td>
                            <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_1" mycustomattr="foo" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">GRP Wear Layer thickness</span>


                        </td><td>
                            <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_1" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">2</span>


                        </td><td>


                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl03$txtBoxOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_1" margin-left="100px" class="txtbox" style="font-family:Georgia;height:28px;width:130px;" type="text">



                        </td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
                <td>
                            <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_2" mycustomattr="foo" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">GRP Surface treatment
    </span>


                        </td><td>
                            <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_2" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">5</span>


                        </td><td>

                             <select name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl04$ddlOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_ddlOpis_2" margin-left="100px" class="ddl" style="font-family:Georgia;height:35px;width:142px;">
                    <option value="1">Proteco Lacquer
    </option>
                    <option value="2">Proteco Hardwax Oil
    </option>
                    <option value="3">Classic Lacquer
    </option>
                    <option value="4">Proteco Natura
    </option>

                </select>
                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl04$txtBoxOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_2" margin-left="100px" class="txtbox" style="font-family: Georgia; height: 28px; width: 130px; display: none;" type="text">


                        </td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
                <td>
                            <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_3" mycustomattr="foo" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">GRP Pattern
    </span>



                        </td><td>
                            <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_3" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">6</span>


                        </td><td>

                             <select name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl05$ddlOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_ddlOpis_3" margin-left="100px" class="ddl" style="font-family:Georgia;height:35px;width:142px;">
                    <option value="1">3 strip
    </option>
                    <option value="2">1 strip
    </option>

                </select>
                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl05$txtBoxOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_3" margin-left="100px" class="txtbox" style="font-family: Georgia; height: 28px; width: 130px; display: none;" type="text">


                        </td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
                <td>
                            <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_4" mycustomattr="foo" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">GRP PIM product hierarchy
    </span>



                        </td><td>
                            <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_4" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">9</span>


                        </td><td>


                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl06$txtBoxOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_4" margin-left="100px" class="txtbox" style="font-family:Georgia;height:28px;width:130px;" type="text">


                        </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

Here's the button:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Save"/>
```

Here's the jquery I have for now:

```
$('#MainContent_btnButton').click(function () {


              alert(
              '' +
              $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_0 ").text() +
              '   ' + 
              $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_0 ").val() +

              '\n' +
              '' +
              $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_1 ").text() +
              '   ' +
              $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_1 ").val() +
              '\n' +
              $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_2 ").text() +
              '   ' +
              $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_2 ").val() +
              '\n' +
              $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_3 ").text() +
              '   ' +

              $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_ddlOpis_3").val() +
              '\n' +
              $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_4 ").text() +
              '   ' +
              $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_4 ").val() +
              '\n' 
              );
          });
```

And the result shown on the button click is :

```
1   text1  -> random text written in textbox
2   text2
5   4    -> selected value in ddl
6   1
```

The jquery is not good because number of labels can be much bigger in first column, and i don't know when textbox and when ddl is going to be shown is second column.

Can someone please help me ?

THanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the data from the table by looping around the rows and their columns and then putting all of them in an object or a string of your choice.

Below is an example of creating an `objectArray`:

```
var myCollection=[];
$('#MainContent_gvKarakteristike tbody').find('tr:gt(1)').each(function(){
 var row = this;
 var myObj={
   karakteristike:valuefromType($(row).find('td:eq(0)').children()),
   label:valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(1)').children()),
   opis:valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(2)').children())
 };
 myCollection[myCollection.length]=myObj;
});

function valuefromType(control)
{
  var type = $(control).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
  switch(type)
  {
    case "input":
    return $(control).val();
    break;
    case "select":
    return $(control).val();
    break;
    case "label":
    return $(control).text();
    break;
    //add other types as for your need
  }
}
```

then later use the object `myCollection` and send it to the Server-Side by serializing it.

Answer (score 0):

@vikscool

THANKS !!!

Code that works look's like this if someone else need's it

```
 var myCollection = [];
                   $('#MainContent_gvKarakteristike tbody').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
                       var row = this;
                       var myObj = {

                           label: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(1)').children())),
                           opis:valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(2)').children()))
                       };
                       myCollection[myCollection.length] = myObj;
                   });

                   function valuefromType(control) {
                       var type = $(control).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
                       switch (type) {
                           case "input":
                               return $(control).val();
                               break;
                           case "span":
                               return $(control).text();
                               break;
                           case "select":
                               return $(control).val();
                               break;
                               //add other types as for your need
                       }
                   }
```

On button click result stored in array is :

```
   0: Object { label: "1", opis: null }
​
1: Object { label: "2", opis: "test2" }
​
2: Object { label: "3", opis: "test3" }
​
3: Object { label: "5", opis: "3" }
​
4: Object { label: "9", opis: "test5" }
​
5: Object { label: "15", opis: "test88" }
```

length: 6

This is what array returns